# How does Magisk mount work? (some words because "Title cannot contain...")

Tags: android, root, mount

I just want to know how does Magisk mount work. First, I've looked at `mount`

```
 ~ # mount
# I show only important information
/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root at /sbin/.magisk/mirror/system_root
tmpfs on /system/bin # It's mounted by Magisk
tmpfs on /system/etc # It's mounted by Magisk
tmpfs on /tmp # My custom mount, made by init.d
/dev/block/mmcblk0p69 on / type ext4 (ro)
 ~ # touch /system/bin/binary
# Success
 ~ # mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /
 ~ # touch /test
Error: read-only system
 / # mount --bind /tmp /vendor/etc
# /tmp is empty
 / # ls /vendor/etc
 / # umount /vendor/etc
 / # ls /vendor/etc
IPACM_cfg.xml
NOTICE.xml.gz
a2dp_in_audio_policy_configuration.xml
acdbdata
audio
...
```

There are a lot of difficult questions. I was asking at ru-StackOverflow, I was finding answers at Google, I read Magisk source code (I know C++, but not very good). There is interesting function in [xwrap.hpp](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/native/jni/utils/xwrap.hpp) (maybe this "magic mount"):

```
int xmount(const char *source, const char *target, const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags, const void *data);
```

Like `mount()` in `sys/mount.h`...  But there is no any activity in `xmount()`! Empty function!

Second question is about tmpfs. Why can I write into [Magisk] tmpfs at `/system/bin` but can't write into tmpfs which I've mounted at `/` by command?

I thank it's made by overlayfs, mhddfs. But my kernel even does not support it! Also, my kernel doesn't support even union-filesystems (unionfs, aufs)! But... What is Magisk mount, how does it works??

Another question. Why does Magisk use custom block devices?

```
 ~ # ls /sbin/.magisk/block
data
system_root
vendor
 ~ # mount | grep /sbin/.magisk/block
/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root on /system/xbin/7z
/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root on /system/xbin/htop
...
 ~ # dd if=/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root of=./system.img
 ~ # losetup /dev/block/loop0 ./system.img
 ~ # mount -t ext4 /dev/block/loop0 /data/local/mnt
 ~ # ls /data/local/mnt/system/bin
# my standard binaries, no modules...
```

*WHAT IS IT??*

1: Can I really connect more than 1 block device with real partition/loop device?

2: I've understood how can I mount into file (into file, not file (like image.img) into anything...). But... One block device on *many* **different** binaries?? Block device which contains only real system partition without modules but mounted into module files???

3: How does Magisk mount tmpfs *really over* system? When I try to write in `/system/bin`, I write at *tmpfs*, not real partition. But when I try to write in *tmpfs* over `/`, I write into real partition.

4: How does Magisk mount modules? It's really not classical `mount --bind`. I've written what will be there if I try to mount any directory into system partition. But when Magisk mounts, I can see real system file near with Magisk modules files and even do anything with system files and Magisk files like they are on the same folder, same partition!

Sorry if my English is not good...

Comment: UPD: I've understood how block devices are mounted into files. It's not block mounted, it's mounted-bind (mount --bind) files. I know how can I mount-bind files. But, for creating empty file for mounting into it, you need write-access. It works by magisk tmpfs in /system/bin, /system/etc. But why I can't write into tmpfs which I've mounted by command? Also, there is an interesting detail: when I try to unmount /system/bin tmpfs, there is an error: Device or resource busy. Are there really tmpfs connected with block device?? It's even not ramfs, how does it work???

Comment: Now I've understood "magic mount"...